# Sort a Map in descending order based on value of arraylist in Java

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist, hashmap

I have a Map of type

```java
static Map<String, ArrayList<String>> Container = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>();
```

The value array list has two elements, the first index is an extension and the second is size,

```
Container : {
C:\HTML\viewer\files\output\ViewerJS\commons-io-2.11.0-src (2).zip=[zip, 919362], 
C:\HTML\viewer\files\jar_files (2).zip=[zip, 345068], 
C:\HTML\viewer\files\output\ViewerJS\rar1.rar=[rar, 1], 
C:\HTML\viewer\files\output\files.zip=[zip, 10184010], 
C:\HTML\viewer\files\check2.zip=[zip, 1]
}
```

I want the map to be sorted in descending order based on the number in index 1 of the map value which is the size which is also of type **STRING**.

A little help would be much appreciated, Thank you.

Comment: hope this link will help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18881182/java-sorting-a-map-by-the-value-when-value-is-an-arraylist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TreeMap` can be sorted *by keys*, and `LinkedHashMap` maintains the insertion order.

Most likely, you need just to sort the output of the map contents in the desired order, which can be implemented like this using simple `Comparator.comparing` and `Comparator.reverseOrder()`:

```java
Container.entrySet()
    .stream()
    .sorted(Comparator.comparing(
        e -> Long.parseLong(e.getValue().get(1)), Comparator.reverseOrder()
    ))
    .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Output:

```
C:\HTML\viewer\files\output\files.zip=[zip, 10184010]
C:\HTML\viewer\files\output\ViewerJS\commons-io-2.11.0-src (2).zip=[zip, 919362]
C:\HTML\viewer\files\jar_files (2).zip=[zip, 345068]
C:\HTML\viewer\files\check2.zip=[zip, 1]
C:\HTML\viewer\files\output\ViewerJS\rar1.rar=[rar, 1]
```

Or the results of sorting may be re-collected into a `LinkedHashMap` (example of using `Map.Entry.comparingByValue`):

```java
Container = Container.entrySet()
    .stream()
    .sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByValue(Comparator.comparing(
        arr -> Long.parseLong(arr.get(1)), Comparator.reverseOrder()
    )))
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(
        Map.Entry::getKey,
        Map.Entry::getValue,
        (a, b) -> a,
        LinkedHashMap::new
    ));
```

Answer (score 1):

This uses a TreeMap and a utility function(addElementsToMap) that would update your map.

Note: A Comparator is provided at map creation time.

```
public class DriverClass {


private static Map<Integer, ArrayList<String>> container = new TreeMap<>((o1, o2) -> (o2 < o1) ? -1 : 1);

public static void main(String[] args) {
    DriverClass driver = new DriverClass();
    String[] elementsList = driver.collectElements();
    driver.addElementsToMap(elementsList);
    container.entrySet().forEach(e -> System.out.println(e.getKey() + " ----- " + e.getValue()));

}

private void addElementsToMap(String[] elementsList) {
     int i = 0;
    for (int j = elementsList.length/2; j <= elementsList.length-1; j++) {
       int size = Integer.parseInt(elementsList[i+1].replaceAll("]", ""));
        container.put(size, new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(elementsList[i], elementsList[i+1])));
        i += 2;
    }
}

private String[] collectElements() {
    return new String[] {
        "C:\\HTML\\viewer\\files\\output\\ViewerJS\\commons-io-2.11.0-src (2).zip=[zip", "919362]",
        "C:\\HTML\\viewer\\files\\jar_files (2).zip=[zip", "345068]",
        " C:\\HTML\\viewer\\files\\output\\ViewerJS\\rar1.rar=[rar", "1]",
        "C:\\HTML\\viewer\\files\\output\\files.zip=[zip", "10184010]",
        "C:\\HTML\\viewer\\files\\check2.zip=[zip", "1]"};
 }
}
```

outputs:

```
10184010 ----- [C:\HTML\viewer\files\output\files.zip=[zip, 10184010]]
919362 ----- [C:\HTML\viewer\files\output\ViewerJS\commons-io-2.11.0-src (2).zip=[zip, 919362]]
345068 ----- [C:\HTML\viewer\files\jar_files (2).zip=[zip, 345068]]
1 ----- [C:\HTML\viewer\files\check2.zip=[zip, 1]]
1 ----- [ C:\HTML\viewer\files\output\ViewerJS\rar1.rar=[rar, 1]]
```

Comment: I noticed that I did not account for duplicate keys. I updated compare(Integer o1, Integer o2) return expression to include duplicate keys.